# issue with Tabcontrol in different .NET frameworks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework-version

I developed a Winforms C# application two years back using Visual Studio 2010 (Target framework: .NET Framework 4 Client Profile).

This application has a Form1 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged with a tabcontrol with multiple tabpages. I bound custom properties of my Form to controls that lie on tabpages which are not visible when the form is constructed. The bindings are like this:

```
BindingSource BndFrom1 = new BindingSource();
BndFrom1.DataSource = typeof(Form1);
BndFrom1.Add(this);

TxtTemperature.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndFrom1, "TemperatureString", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

This worked fine. After switching to Windows 10 with .NET Framework 4.6 the application suddenly didn't work propper, it became slow or jammed fully when switching to another tabpage. If I changed the order of the tabpages, it was always the first tabpage that worked fine. 
I tried to "force" Form1 to create the invissible controls by calling

```
private static void CreateControls(Control control)
        {
            CreateControl(control);
            foreach (Control subcontrol in control.Controls)
            {
                CreateControl(subcontrol);
            }
        }
        private static void CreateControl(Control control)
        {
            var method = control.GetType().GetMethod("CreateControl", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var parameters = method.GetParameters();

            method.Invoke(control, new object[] { true });
        }
```

on all tabpages, but this didn't work.
After I removed all databindings  with controls on tabpages, the problem was solved.

I had the first version of my app, with the databindings, still running propper on a Windows 7 PC. But after an update to .NET Framework 4.7, it had the same problems and after installing the new version of the app it was gone.

Is this a known problem and if so, is there an explanation and solution for it? Does anyone have a better solution with which I can keep using bindings?

Thanks in advance,

Elec

Answer (score 0):

We had tried to reproduce this bug, but with no success. Could you please share a sample application that would demonstrate the problem?
Here is what we did:
    1. Create a winforms application
    2. Add a label and a tabcontrol with 2 tabs to the form
    3. Add a textbox to the second tab in the tabcontrol
    4. Data-bind label on the form to a property on the form where the property reflects content of the textbox on the second tab
Do you see what is missing in this repro attempt compared to your code? We had also experimented with data binding to an SQL database. And did not see any difference on 4.0 and 4.7 versions of the framework.

Here is the Form1.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Form1);
            bindingSource.Add(this);

            label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "CustomProperty1", true,
                DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string CustomProperty1 {
            get { return textBox1.Text; }
            set {
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "thing1";
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomProperty1");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you, Tanya